# Django rest framework POST many to many with extra fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a model in Django that has a many-to-many relationship to another model with extra fields. I am using the rest framework to provide CRUD operations on these and am having a chicken-and-egg scenario I believe...

The issue is that when I go to POST the new `MainObject`, it throws an error in the many-to-many part due to not having a `MainObject` id to point to. But I want it to point to the `MainObject` I am creating, which doesn't exist at time of POST'ing. I believe this to be an issue with the serializers, but am unsure of how to resolve it. I assume my assumptions might also be off in how I am formulating the POST data.

I am using Django 2.1.8

**Model Code**

```
class RelatedObject(models.Model):
    ...

class MainObject(models.Model):
    related_objects = models.ManyToManyField(RelatedObject, through='ManyRelatedObject')

class ManyRelatedObject(models.Model):
    main_object = models.ForeignKey(MainObject, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    related_object = models.ForeignKey(RelatedObject, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    other_attribute = models.BooleanField(...)
```

**Serializer Code**

```
class ManyRelatedObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    main_object = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=MainObject.objects.all())
    related_object = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=RelatedObject.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = ManyRelatedObject
        fields = '__all__'


class MainObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    related_object = ManyRelatedObjectSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MainObject
        fields = '__all__'
```

**POST Payload** 
( It is assumed that there exists a `RelatedObject` that has an id of 1)

```
{
  "related_object": [
    {
      "related_object": 1,
      "other_attribute": true
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "related_object": [
    {
      "main_object": [
        "This field is required."
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Goal Response:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "related_object": [
    {
      "main_object": 1,
      "related_object": 1,
      "other_attribute": true
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

**REST endpoint setup**

```
class MainObjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MainObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MainObjectSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the **`__init__()`** method of the **`MainObjectSerializer`**.

```
class MainObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.context['request'].method == 'GET':
            self.fields['related_object'] = ManyRelatedObjectSerializer(many=True) 


    related_object = ManyRelatedObjectSerializer(many=True)# remove this line

    class Meta:
        model = MainObject
        fields = '__all__'
```

What this snippt do is, the serializer will render the response/output using **`ManyRelatedObjectSerializer`** serializer, if the request is a ***`HTTP GET`***, otherwise it will render the *stock mode*(`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`)

Comment: I gave this a shot, but it seemed to ignore the field in the POST... Any ideas? I've been trying to play around with doing this kind of thing in the `ManyRelatedObjectSerializer`, but no success there either

Comment: One of the main thing is the `related_object` filed should be belongs to `MainObject` model and the `fields` should be **`__all__`**

Comment: This is how it is currently set up, as in the question.

Comment: What kind of thing would you expect to be missing?

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, ended up hand-jamming this with poorly overridden `create` and `update` methods, due to time constraints. Seems ridiculous that django can't handle this scenario, seems like it's a fairly common use case...